# Using Text::CSV to parse a tab delimited file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, csv

I am trying to make use of the `Text::CSV` Perl module to be able to parse a tab delimited file.

The file I am trying to parse is:

```
#IGNORE COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4
ROW1    x   y   z   a
ROW2    b   c   d   
ROW3    w
```

Note that the file is tab delimited. This file may have `N` columns and `N` rows. Also, in the case of `ROW2`, it has a fourth tab but no value. `ROW3` has no tabs after the `w` value for `COLUMN1`. I.e. some columns may have undefined values or blank values.

So far, I have began writing a Perl script but have stumbled very early on in trying to figure out how I can write code to answer the following question:

Find out how many `ROWn` there are. Then for each `COLUMNn` check to see if I have `ROWn` values. So in this case, `COLUMN2`,`COLUMN3` and `COLUMN4` would have missing values.

Any tips and guidance would help (I'm new to Perl). I've looked at the CPAN Text::CSV page but I've not managed to be able to solve this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use v5.12;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({
     escape_char         => '"',
     sep_char            => '\t',
     eol                 => $\,
     binary              => 1,
     blank_is_undef      => 1,
     empty_is_undef      => 1,
     });

open (my $file, "<", "tabfile.txt") or die "cannot open: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($file)) {
    say @$row[0];
}
close($file);
```

Comment: If you can have both blank fields (multiple tabs in a row) and non-existent fields (line ends prematurely), would you count blank fields the same as non-existent?

Comment: @TLP Yes. Basically, a row may have multiple tabs where the value is "blank" (e.g. in `ROW2`, `COLUMN4` has an "empty" tab value or the line may end prematurely like it does in `ROW3` where there is NO character after the `w` in `COLUMN1`

Comment: Use `sep_char => "\t"` as `'\t'` makes the separator literally `\t` and not the tab character.

Comment: @user2402135 So what is the problem you are having? That you do not know how to count the elements of `$row`? That you do not know how to compare empty and undefined?

Comment: @TLP Well from having looked at the Text::CSV CPAN page I am not able to access each row x column reference in order to be able to compare empty and undefined or be able to count the elements in the row. If I could locate/access the "elements" that make up my tab delimited table then I can easily continue :)

Comment: @Kenosis of course you're right I didn't spot this. Thanks.

Comment: I see, so basically you were just failing to report the real error you were having: That the row printed all at once. How did you manage to ask a question like this and not include that rather vital piece of information? On that note, I think you probably also didn't mean that eol should be `$\ ` (the output record separator, default undef), but `rather $/` the *input* record separator, default newline.

Comment: The first question by @TLP was the difference between "blank" and "missing". Are you trying to find any rows that do not have the right number of fields, or trying to find fields that exist and are "blank"? Of 4 fields, `"1\t\t3\t4"` and `"1\t2\t3"` both are missing 1 value, only one is missing a field.

Comment: @sln The OP asked a clear, lucid and elaborate question but failed to explain that s/he got the entire line printed with `say @$row[0]` (because the faulty sep_char `'\t'` would fail to identify any fields).

Comment: @TLP - Didn't see that, so each row parsed to 1 field. Problem solved!

Comment: It seems that the problem is solved, but I have a tiny suggestion. My [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie::Array::CSV) can make some of this code much simpler, if you are interested.

Comment: @JoelBerger: Hi Joel. I'm interested to see that module in action, and of course would upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach where for each line process every field and increment a counter when it's not `false`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my (@col_counter); 
my ($line_counter, $r, $num_cols) = (0, 0, 0); 

open my $fh, '<', shift or die;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    sep_char => qq|\t|
});

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) { 
    ## First row (header), get the number of columns.
    if ( $line_counter == 0 ) { 
        $num_cols = $#$row;
        next;
    }
    ## For each data row, traverse every column and increment a 
    ## counter if it has any value.
    for ( 1 .. $#$row ) { 
        ++$col_counter[ $_ ] if $row->[ $_ ];
    }   
}
continue {
    $line_counter++;
}

printf qq|Lines of file: %d\n|, $line_counter - 1;
## Check if any column has missing values. For each column compare the 
## number of lines read (substract 1 of header) with its counter. If they
## are different it means that the column had any row without value.
for my $i ( 1 .. $num_cols ) { 
    $r = $line_counter - 1 - (defined $col_counter[ $i ] ? $col_counter[ $i ] : 0); 
    if ( $r > 0 ) { 
        printf qq|Column %d has %d missing values\n|, $i, $r;  
    }   
}
```

With your example data, run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
Lines of file: 3
Column 2 has 1 missing values
Column 3 has 1 missing values
Column 4 has 2 missing values
```

---

**UPDATE**: See comments. I do the reverse looking for columns that don't contain any value and appends current line number to an array, and use `join` to extract all lines.

What parts did I change? Here to save line numbers.

```
for ( 1 .. $num_cols ) { 
    push @{ $col_counter[ $_ ] }, $line_counter unless $row->[ $_ ];
}
```

And here to print them. You will need to comment the old behaviour.

```
if ( defined $col_counter[ $i ] ) { 
    printf qq|Column %d has no value in lines %s\n|, $i, join q|,|, @{ $col_counter[ $i ] };
}
```

It yields:

```
Lines of file: 3
Column 2 has no value in lines 3
Column 3 has no value in lines 3
Column 4 has no value in lines 2,3
```

Comment: this code does not seem to work when my file looks like this: 

`#IGNORE COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4
row1 x x x
row2.` 


It is not aware that 2 values are missing for `COLUMN4`

Comment: @user2402135: In your input file `column4` has two missed values. I don't understand your example.

Comment: If I change the input file above so that `COLUMN4` has NO row values whatsoever, then this whole column is ignored when the missing values are printed. I want to be able to print that `COLUMN4` has `N` missing values if it has zero values. At the moment, the code just ignores `COLUMN4` if it has no values at all.

Comment: @user2402135: I've fixed it to extract the number of columns from the header.

Comment: now i seems to be completely broken. I doesn't even recognise any missing values.

Comment: @user2402135: Your data will be somewhat different. I've tested it either with and without a value in `column4` and the output is what I posted. But the script is there and I hope easy to understand, so simply go step by step with a debugger to see the point where it breaks.

Comment: it works thank you! could you please help explain what the code does? I am new to Perl. thanks

Comment: @user2402135: I've updated the code with comments. The key of the program is that for each column it increments a counter when a value appears and at the end compares this value with the number of lines, and must be equal.

Comment: how can you change the above code so that it prints the missing row name as opposed to the number of missing values?

I've got very close and am able to print the missing row names but i just can't associate/link them to the respective column heading name.

Comment: @user2402135: What do you mean with **missing row**?

Comment: What I mean to say is that instead of the script printing out "Column 2 has 1 missing values", How can it be changed so that it prints out "Column 2 has 1 missing values for the row ID ROW3". In other words, instead of print out the number of missing values for a column like it currently does, print the NAME of the ROW for which there is a missing value. I hope that is clearer :)

Comment: @user2402135: I've updated the script. I don't like to do this because of two reasons, you are changing requirements from the original question and you didn't show any effort to adapt what I had already done. You were a bit lucky today :-)